# defining GET function for a RESTful web service using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

given a RESTful web service that allows different users to post different articles

For defining the `GET` function on the server-sidem 
i suppose there should be async functions like `list`, `getTopViewed`, `getTopFavorite` etc functions on the server-side

**is the following correct then?**

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {

    db.articles.list(function etc)
    db.articles.getTopViewed(function etc)
    db.articles.getTopFavorite(function etc)
}
```

NOTE: where `list`, `getTopViewed` and `getTopFavorite` are defined in another JavaScript file

In another JS file:

```
exports.list = function(callback){
  // acts as async callback 
  var result = ArticleModel.find({}, function(err, articles){
    callback(null, articles)                                                    
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Are those methods synchronous? If not, you want something like the `async` module. You also need to respond at some point. BTW, it's usually correct if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using something like [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) or [Express](http://expressjs.com/). It has a router that makes this a bit easier. Setup and usage look something like this:

```
var express = require("express"),
    db = require('./yourdb.js');

var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get("/articles/", function(req, res){
    db.list(function(err, articles){
       res.writeHead(200);
       // you probably want to do something more complex here
       res.end(JSON.stringify(articles));
    });
});

app.get("/articles/top", function(req, res){
    // res.end(<top articles go here>);
});
```

Here's a link to the docs for Express' router: [Application Routing](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB)

Comment: im using mongoose and express

Comment: may i know whats the difference between using `export.get = function(req, res)` and using `app.get("/articles/top")` ?

Comment: `exports.get` will define a function in a module named `get`. You use this when you're including another js file using `require`. It's part of node's module system